# Homepage not show page content in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

Homepage not show page content in magento?
I check with inspect element withe firebug there one 
This div style display: none; If I remove this style in inspect element then show page content.
Please tell me how to remove display none of this div and then show the content.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it can be due to several reasons.
Are you using a specific theme ? does this theme provide options ?
Did you check if this css property (display:none;) is in a css class or in the style attribute ?
Did you check if was editable in the cms page directly ?

The css display:none seems to be the cause, but to locate what is the best way to remove it is another one .

Comment: display:none applied on main class not inline.I checked in cms page.

Comment: is this a specific class for your theme ? just remove the display:none; in the css file.. but at your own risk because it was probably set for a purpose, maybe this theme is using jquery and it has compatibility problem, check as well if you have some js errors log in the js console of your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common mistake, probably style-sheet of another extension/theme share the same CSS selector and override the previous style.

You have to look carefully and remove it using `!important` attribute.

Note: 
    if you are not sure about that particular selector is used on some other page/block, you should write fully qualified and unique selector in CSS and use `display:block !important;`